# An angle $\theta$ can be trisected if and only if the polynomial $ 4 x^3-3 x-\cos \theta $ is reducible over $\mathbb{Q}(\cos \theta)$

Tags: trigonometry, polynomials, field-theory

An angle $\theta$ can be trisected  if and only if the polynomial $$ 4 x^3-3 x-\cos \theta $$ is reducible over $\mathbb{Q}(\cos \theta)$

My try

I do it by contradiction so for $\rightarrow$

i Suppose that we can trisect an angle $\theta$ but $ 4 x^3-3 x-\cos \theta $ is irreducible in $\mathbb{Q}(\cos \theta)$

then  $\phi=\frac{\theta}{3}$ is constructible

First we have
$cos\theta=cos3\phi=4cos^3\phi-3cos\phi$

so $4cos^3\phi-3cos\phi-cos\theta=0$

then $cos\phi$ must be a root of $4x^3-3x-cos\theta$

but $4x^3-3x-cos\theta$ is irreducible (in order to get a contradiction)

then we have that $[\mathbb Q(\cos \theta,\cos \phi):\mathbb Q(\cos \theta)]=3$

but 3 is not of the form $2^k$ so $\phi $ is not constructible so its a contradiction

then $4x^3-3x-cos\theta$ have to be reducible in $\mathbb{Q}(\cos \theta)$

and for $\leftarrow$ I think its the same

I do it by contrapositive

I suppose that $ 4 x^3-3 x-\cos \theta $ is irreducible in $\mathbb{Q}(\cos \theta)$

then

$[\mathbb Q(\cos \theta,\cos \phi):\mathbb Q(\cos \theta)]=3$

and then $cos\phi$ is not constructible is this right?

Comment: For the $\Leftarrow$ direction you say contrapositive, but it looks like you're then proving the inverse of that direction of implication (which is equivalent to the $\Rightarrow$ direction instead).  Hint for that direction: if $4x^3 - 3x - \cos\theta$ is reducible, then that it implies it has a root in $\mathbb{Q}(\cos\theta)$; and that root must be one of $\cos(\frac{1}{3} \theta)$, $\cos(\frac{1}{3} \theta + \frac{2\pi}{3})$, or $\cos(\frac{1}{3} \theta + \frac{4\pi}{3})$.

Comment: @DanielSchepler  $\cos(\frac{1}{3} \theta + \frac{2\pi}{3})$? or $\cos(\frac{1}{3} \phi + \frac{2\pi}{3})$